# I'm using the maven-javadoc-plugin, how can I include documentation from other modules together?

Tags: java, javadoc, maven-javadoc-plugin

I have two modules, A and B, and A depends on B. They are completely separate, and B is deployed and used in an internal repository.

You want to use the maven-javadoc-plugin for documentation in A, but you also want to include the contents of B's dependent modules. For example, you might have something like this

```
RespostDTO testMethod(int a) { // blabla }
```

Assuming we have the above method in A's module, `RespostDTO` is B's module code. In this case, we want to see the JavaDoc corresponding to `RespostDTO` in the documentation created in A. How can we do this?

What should I do for A and B modules?

Answer (score 2):

You can explicitly add dependencies into javadoc generation:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <sourcepath>${basedir}/src/main/java</sourcepath>
        <includeDependencySources>true</includeDependencySources>
        <dependencySourceIncludes>
            <dependencySourceInclude>some.group.id1:*</dependencySourceInclude>
            <dependencySourceInclude>some.group.id2:artifactId2</dependencySourceInclude>
        </dependencySourceIncludes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Source:
https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/examples/aggregate-dependency-sources.html#fine-tuning-included-dependencies

Comment: Thanks for the advice.
In the module you gave as an example (some.group.id2:artifactId2), what should we do?

Comment: this is just a reference to the dependency you want to see in generated docs. in your case it's module B.

Comment: I've posted a separate question in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75758892/how-can-we-include-javadocs-in-a-javamodule-deployment , but I'm also curious about the pom configuration for module B. What should be the configuration for module B?